# Rubyで文字列からn文字を分岐なく取り出すには

Tags: ruby

Rubyで文字列末尾からn文字を取り出したいです

Ruby の String#slice は、第一引数に「文字列の長さ+1」を超える絶対値を持つ数値を渡すと nil を返却します
そのため、安易に `str.slice(-n, -1)` としてしまうと nil が返却されてしまい、nil チェックなしに String のメソッドを利用すると NoMethodError が発生してしまいます
(n は必ず正の整数です)

Ruby では「文字列の末尾n文字を得る」という至極単純な操作を分岐なしに実現することは本当にできないのでしょうか?
`str.slice(-n, -1) || ""` で限界なのでしょうか?

Comment: まぁ、`str.chars.last(n).join` などとすればできなくはないですね…

Comment: 「文字列の末尾n文字を得る」は単純な操作なんでしょうか?

Comment: ruby は perl 由来なので substr("abc", -10) などが成功するのではないかと考えました
JS は str.slice(-n), python は str[-n:] で実現できます
JavaやC#はRangeErrorが発生するので分岐が必要ですが、「文字列のn文字目以降全て」を取得するメソッドがあります

Comment: もしかして str.slice(-n, -1) は str.slice(-n..-1)  （str[-n..-1]）でしょうか？ ruby の String#slice() で第二引数は取得する文字数のはずですが…　https://ref.xaio.jp/ruby/classes/string/slice

Comment: そもそも「n > 文字列の長さ」 の場合に何を取得したいのでしょうか？ python の str[-n:] やJSの str.slice(-n) と同じ動作とするなら文字列全体( str と同等の文字列)ですが、示されたコードを見ると空文字列を取得しています。どちらでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

元の文字列を`str`、欲しい末尾からの文字数が`n`とした場合

```rb
str.slice((str.length - n), n) || str
```

という方法があるとおもいます。

`||`以降は、length < n の場合、全文字列を返すことで足りないけど、後ろから`n`文字は全文字列だよという感じで

Answer (score 2):

もしかしたら、どなたかがシンプルで使いやすいイディオムを思いつくかもしれないですが、あなたがお書きになった

`str.slice(-n, -1) || ""`

で十分かと思います。

> 安易に str.slice(-n, -1) としてしまうと nil が返却されてしまい、nil チェックなしに String のメソッドを利用すると NoMethodError が発生してしまいます

とありますが、

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-slice

に

> slice(start, length) → new_str or nil

と、ご存知の通り nil を返す仕様です。
これを nil ではなく空文字を返す仕様にする方法はないかということと同じことだと思います。そういったメソッドは無いので、既存の似たようなメソッド（今回はnilを返す）に空文字を返してくれといっても無理です。

ちなみに`Array`には`fetch`という該当するインデックスが無い場合、デフォルトの値を変わりに取得するメソッドがありますが、この`fetch`は範囲を指定することができないので、似ているがやはり違う用途となります。`fetch`と`slice`を参考にご自身で欲しいメソッドを作ったほうがよいかと考えます。

Answer (score 2):

式展開すればnilの部分は空文字になりますのでお望みの結果が得られると思います。

```rb
"#{str[-n..-1]}"
```

Comment: nil を空文字列にしたいというのが要求されているなら str[-n..-1].to_s でもよさそうですね。(NilClass の to_s メソッドは空文字列を返却するので)

Answer (score 0):

他の皆様の回答を読んで、@gochoさんが本当に欲しいものが解らなくなったので、補足です。

以降の処理でn文字の文字列が必要で、後ろからn文字が意味を持つのであれば、

```
str = " " * n + str
lastn = str.slice((str.length - n), n)
```

とすることで、長さが必ず`n`で、空白により右詰めの文字列を得る方法もあると思います。
こうすると、`str`の内容が`""`でも`n`個の`" "`が得られるので、以降の処理で`n`文字以上ある事が前提の場合、以降の処理で落ちない事が保証されます。